Supporting both AMD and ES6 modules
Is there a syntax that allows a library to be compatible with being loaded as either an AMD or ES6 module?  Right now I have two different *.js files for each module.  One with a define(()=>{ ... for AMD and one with a export { ModuleName} for ES6.  The export keyword doesn't seem to be valid for anywhere other than root scope, so trying to place it in any kind of conditional does not work.  If loaded as an AMD module, it generates the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'.
This is a .NET WASM library that contains some static JS resources, and there are two scenarios that users would consume the library.  One using AMD and the other ES6.  I don't really have a JavaScript compilation pipeline that allows me to detect the usage scenario at the downstream developer's compile time to conditionally generate adjusted JS.  So trying to determine if there's a syntax that will operate correctly in both scenarios when the module is loaded at runtime.
This is my unsuccessful attempt at dual compatibility:
let SomeInteropHelpers = globalThis.SomeInteropHelpers || {};
define(() => {
    
    (function (SomeInteropHelpers) {
        var HelpersProxy = SomeInteropHelpers.HelpersProxy || {};// create child namespace

        HelpersProxy.GetArrayObjectItems = function (arrayObject) {
            return arrayObject.items;
        }

        HelpersProxy.Check = function () {
            console.log('Checked');
        };

        SomeInteropHelpers.HelpersProxy = HelpersProxy; // add to parent namespace

    })(SomeInteropHelpers || globalThis.SomeInteropHelpers || (globalThis.SomeInteropHelpers = {}));
    
});

export { SomeInteropHelpers };


"I don't really have a JavaScript compilation pipeline that allows me to detect the usage scenario at the downstream developer's compile time to conditionally generate adjusted JS." - you don't need that pipeline. The developer using your library does - and they usually have one. You should distribute multiple versions of your code, one with exports syntax and one with AMD syntax, and declare them in your package.json so that the user of your library will automatically bundle the one they need.

"I'm trying to determine if there's a syntax that will operate correctly in both scenarios when the module is loaded at runtime" - there is no such syntax, sorry.

try this
(function (root, factory) {
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([], factory);
} else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
} else {
    // Browser globals (root is window)
    root.SomeInteropHelpers = factory();
}}(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this, function () {
// Create a namespace object
var SomeInteropHelpers = {};

// Your module code goes here
(function (SomeInteropHelpers) {
    var HelpersProxy = SomeInteropHelpers.HelpersProxy || {};

    HelpersProxy.GetArrayObjectItems = function (arrayObject) {
        return arrayObject.items;
    };

    HelpersProxy.Check = function () {
        console.log('Checked');
    };

    SomeInteropHelpers.HelpersProxy = HelpersProxy;
})(SomeInteropHelpers);

return SomeInteropHelpers;}));


This does not contain a export declaration that allows it to be used as a module.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
